# Insert query - Error converting data type nvarchar to (null)

Tags: sql, sql-server, historian

I'm trying to insert data from SQL Server to a Linked server but I am encountering the following issue:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 11, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to (null).
```

My query is:

```
INSERT piserver.piarchive..picomp2 
(tag, time, value, annotations)
SELECT cast(c.name as nvarchar) as name, convert(datetime, c.started_at) as started_at, c.value, cast(c.log as nvarchar) as log
FROM [database].[dbo].[table1] c
WHERE c.id = 206
```

There are no null values in the first 3 columns, but even when I remove the last column from the query, I am still met with a null error.

The datatypes of picomp2 are:
tag (WString(4000), not null)
time (DateTime, not null)
value (Variant, null)
annotations (Variant, null)

The datatypes of table1 are all varchar except value which is float.

Comment: Is there more columns in the table you are trying to insert into that may not allow nulls that you dont have in your query?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: @Brad, yes, there's an _index column but I believe it's auto generated if not provided. The following query in the same format works in the SQL commander program without it, but not in SQL Server.  `INSERT piserver.piarchive..picomp2 (tag, time, value, annotations)
VALUES ('Test.Test1', '2021-02-20 04:48:06', 1.0, 'Manually created')`

Comment: This looks like a long standing [known issue with variants](https://pisquare.osisoft.com/s/question/0D51I00004UHeAa/insert-into-picomp2-using-linked-server).

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you always want to include a length.  The default varies by context.  It is not clear what the lengths should be, but yo ucan probably just rely on implicit conversion to do the right thing:

```
INSERT piserver.piarchive..picomp2 (tag, time, value, annotations)
    SELECT c.name, try_convert(datetime, c.started_at) as started_at, c.value, c.log 
    FROM [database].[dbo].[table1] c
    WHERE c.id = 206;
```

I also recommend using `try_convert()` for the `datetime`, unless you want conversion errors to stop the `INSERT`.